# Redrawing a plane with a slider

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, mplot3d

Given a 3D surface plot in matplotlib which is described by a plane in the form of Z = a*X+b*y+d. Further given a slider by which the a-parameter of Z should be controlled. I got so far the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

x = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,10)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=0.12861723162963065*X + 0.0014024845304814665*Y + 1.0964608113924048

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)


ax_a = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
s_a = Slider(ax_a, 'A', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=5)


def update(val):
    A = s_a.val
    Z1=A*X + 0.0014024845304814665*Y + 1.0964608113924048
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
s_a.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

It plots so far an initial plane. It draws also the new planes if the slider is moved. However, it does not remove the old planes in the 3D plot.

The question here is: how can I 'update' to the new plane whenever the slider is moved?

Best regards

Comment: You cannot (easily) update an existing surface plot. But you can remove any artist via `artist.remove()`.